# Do I need to declare header files or cxx files or both in a make file?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, visual-studio-code

I read a good tutorial about makefiles, but got a bit confused when things became more complex.

I restructured my workspace Folder and added subfolder: Here is an image of my workspace folder:

[image: Workspace Folder Tree]

I tried to edit the makefile, but still don't succeed making it compile my files.

Do I only need to declare header files in make files or do I need both, header and cxx files?

In the makefile I declared how to build a release and a debug build. I tried to say: create the debug .o files in the debug folder and link them together in debug to an executable called exefile. Since I added the subfolders include and src this got messed up and I do not know how to edit the makefile properly now.

Here is the code of the makefile:

```
#Compiler Flags#

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra
HDIR = include

#Project Files#
SRCS = src/main.cxx src/ex05_01.cxx src/ex05_02.cxx
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cxx=.o)
EXE = exefile

#Debug Build Settings#
DBGDIR = debug
DBGEXE = $(DBGDIR)/$(EXE)
DBGOBJS = $(addprefix $(DBGDIR)/, $(OBJS))
DBGCFLAGS = -g -O0 -DDEBUG

#Release Build Settings#
RELDIR = Release
RELEXE = $(RELDIR)/$(EXE)
RELOBJS = $(addprefix $(RELDIR)/, $(OBJS))
RELFLAGS = -g -O0 -DNDEBUG

.PHONY: all clean debug prep release remake

#default build
debug: $(DBGEXE)

$(DBGEXE): $(DBGOBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DBGCFLAGS) -o $(DBGEXE) $^

$(DBGDIR)/%.o: %.cxx
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DBGCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# Release rules
release: $(RELEXE)

$(RELEXE): $(RELOBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(RELCFLAGS) -o $(RELEXE) $^

$(RELDIR)/%.o: %.cxx
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(RELCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# Other rules
prep: mkdir -p $(DBGDIR) $(RELDIR)

remake: 
    clean all

clean:
    rm -f $(RELEXE) $(RELOBJS) $(DBGEXE) $(DBGOBJS)
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I forgot to post the error message of make:

> *** No rule to make target `debug/main.o', needed by`debug/exefile'.  Stop.

Comment: You won't have to declare the header files in the makefile, but you have to name **all** used code-files (in your case cxx).

Comment: okay, but that's what I did here: SRCS = src/main.cxx src/ex05_01.cxx src/ex05_02.cxx

Comment: Your error message tells you that the actual error lies somewhere else. Check if there actually is a file named main.o in /debug/

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: but itzFlubby said it's not necessary to declare the include path, only cxx files? now I get confused

Comment: @itzFlubby: no files in debug

Comment: And there is the problem: The error says exactly that -> namely that the file main.o is needed, but can't be found. Sometimes it help deleting the debug folder and to try again

Comment: @HardCodedCoder - you are correct as long as your souces can see and include your headers in `include`. Then I agree your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: now I edited the line:                                                 $(DBGDIR)/%.o: src/%.cxx
  $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DBGCFLAGS) -o $@ $<                                                     i added src/ to %.cxx and now he doesn't find the h files

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how can I fix this?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: g++ -c -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g -O0 -DDEBUG -o debug/main.o src/main.cxx
src/main.cxx:2:10: fatal error: 'ex05_01.h' file not found
#include "ex05_01.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Makefiles. First you need to figure out how to compile your files manually (running `g++` directly, etc). Then you can start automating the process by putting the right commands in a Makefile.

Comment: I'm looking and it is hard to tell with pasted makefiles, but you do have tab-characters `'\t'` (not spaces) following your targets right? In between the targers and the recipes? Like `"debug:\t$(DBGEXE)"` and then before each remaining line in the target?

Comment: What commands are you using to compile your code without a Makefile?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: yeah, I'm only using tabs and no spaces!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I guess the problem is exactly what you said now: he cannot find the header files in the include paths! What do I need to add so that he sees the .h files now?

Comment: Adding an `-I/path/to/includes` (simply `-I./include` here) as a compiler option should do it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: yes!!!! Working now!!!! Thx!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Sometimes it's just the little things `:)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You should include rules for the header file dependencies as well. Assuming that main.cxx depends on ex05_01.h, when ex05_01.h changes, you would want main.cxx to be recompiled. Something like this would do the job:

   ```
   main.o: ex05_01.h ... (add more headers if you have)
   ```

   (repeat for all .o files)
2. Your debug and release builds only differ by a few things: an output folder DIR and a DEBUG/NDEBUG define flag in FLAGS. To avoid duplicating all the settings, you could refactor and make common targets, and then switch between your settings with a conditional over a variable, for example, if you run make like so:

   ```
   make BUILD=REL <target>
   ```

   you will get a variable BUILD defined with "REL" value, then you can use `ifeq` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html#Conditional-Example ) to set your DIR and FLAGS accordingly.

Comment: Most compilers can output those include-file-dependencies when compiling. And they can be automatically included in the makefile for further runs.